# Getting input from reactions not working discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I wanted to make a rock paper scissor game for my bot:
[The bot creates an embed with instructions and reacts with a "rock", "paper", and "scissor" emoji, which the user has to click to input his/her choice.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEgvb.png)

But the problem is that the code doesn't go any further and shows an error.

Here is the code:

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["rock_paper_scissors","rps"])
async def _rps(ctx):    #rps is short for rock, paper, scissor
    emojis = ['✊', '️', '✌️']
    
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="CHOOSE YOUR WEAPON!",description = "Choose between rock, paper, or scissors, {}." . format(ctx.author.mention), color = 0xff9900)
    embedVar.add_field(name=":fist: ROCK", value="React with :fist: emoji to choose rock.", inline = False)
    embedVar.add_field(name=":hand_splayed: PAPER", value="React with :hand_splayed: emoji to choose paper.", inline = False)
    embedVar.add_field(name=":v: SCISSORS", value="React with :v: emoji to choose scissors.", inline = False)
    emb = await ctx.send(embed = embedVar)

    for emoji in emojis:
        await emb.add_reaction(emoji)

    def chk(reaction):
        return reaction.emb == emb and reaction.channel == ctx.channel
    
    react = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=chk)

    if react == '✊':
        await ctx.send("You chose rock!")
    elif react == '️':
        await ctx.send("You chose paper!")
    elif react == '✌️':
        await ctx.send("You chose scissors!")
```

I am getting this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: chk() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I tried many fixes but in vain.

Also, I want the bot to accept the input only from the user who had asked for the rock paper scissor game by the command in the first place (the author of the message, in other words), But I am not sure how to implement that, I tried, but it did not work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

`reaction_add` gives a tuple of a reaction and a user so in the `chk` function you need to have both the reaction and user. You should also use `and  user == ctx.author` within the `chk` function to ensure the user is the same.

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["rock_paper_scissors","rps"])
async def _rps(ctx):    #rps is short for rock, paper, scissor
    emojis = ['✊', '️', '✌️']
    
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="CHOOSE YOUR WEAPON!",description = "Choose between rock, paper, or scissors, {}." . format(ctx.author.mention), color = 0xff9900)
    embedVar.add_field(name=":fist: ROCK", value="React with :fist: emoji to choose rock.", inline = False)
    embedVar.add_field(name=":hand_splayed: PAPER", value="React with :hand_splayed: emoji to choose paper.", inline = False)
    embedVar.add_field(name=":v: SCISSORS", value="React with :v: emoji to choose scissors.", inline = False)
    emb = await ctx.send(embed = embedVar)

    for emoji in emojis:
        await emb.add_reaction(emoji)

    def chk(reaction, user):
        return reaction.emb == emb and reaction.channel == ctx.channel and user == ctx.author
    
    react, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=chk)

    if react == '✊':
        await ctx.send("You chose rock!")
    elif react == '️':
        await ctx.send("You chose paper!")
    elif react == '✌️':
        await ctx.send("You chose scissors!")
```

Comment: heyy, I tried what you said, here::
```python
def chk(reaction):
        return reaction.emb == emb and reaction.channel == ctx.channel and  user == ctx.author
    
    react, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=chk)
```
But I am getting the same error... am i missing something?

Comment: Please use the code I provided @NISH_Original

Comment: @NISH_Original if my answer solved your problem you may mark mine as correct with a tick.