# How do i save discord reaction as a variable

Tags: python, input, discord, discord.py

I have this code that sends a message with  4 reactions, is there a way to take the first reaction a user inputs (it has to take only one input if the user chooses another option and it overrides the first one that is also fine) and save it as a variable to use later on?

```
import discord
import os
client = discord.Client()
some_list = []
msg = None

    
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  msg = await message.channel.send("**Question 1?**")
  reactions = ['1️⃣','2️⃣','3️⃣','4️⃣']
  for emoji in reactions: 
    await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.message == msg:
        some_list.append(user)
client.run("token")
```

**Thanks in Advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for) an example of how to use this can be found on my previous answer: [Getting input from reactions not working discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66150175/getting-input-from-reactions-not-working-discord-py/66150514#66150514)

You should really use a dictionary if you don't want to go with wait_for.

```py
import discord
import os
client = discord.Client()
some_dict = {}
msg = None

    
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  msg = await message.channel.send("**Question 1?**")
  reactions = ['1️⃣','2️⃣','3️⃣','4️⃣']
  for emoji in reactions: 
    await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.message == msg:
        some_dict[user.id] = str(reaction.emoji)
client.run("token")
```

You can then access it using `some_dict[user.id]`